# How to make unique random sentence

Tags: php, random

hei,

I need a random words in my sentences 
like this, you have 4 words = 'Crazy','Lidya','Super','Hello'
then i need to make the result like this
example:
LidyaHello or HelloSuper

```
<?php
$role = array("Crazy","Lidya","Super","Hello");
$tamvan = $role[array_rand($role)];
echo $tamvan,$tamvan;
?>
```

but the result that i get is the same word 
example : LidyaLidya or HelloHello

Comment: Well you only get ONE randon word and then echo the same word twice. **What did you expect**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way I know of to randomize without repeating:

```
shuffle($role);

echo implode(array_slice($role, 0, 2));
```

---

The reason the way you're doing it now shows the same word twice:

1. You set a variable to a random element of the array

   ```
   $tamvan = $role[array_rand($role)];
   ```
2. You echo that variable twice.

   ```
   echo $tamvan,$tamvan;
   ```

Echoing `$tamvan` the second time *does not* make `$tamvan = $role[array_rand($role)];` run again.

Answer (score 0):

Dont panics is best answer, but here is a lower level whats going on under the hood answer I was double checking. There will be repeats sometimes

```
 <?php
    $role = array("Crazy","Lidya","Super","Hello");
    $num1 = rand(0,3);
    $num2 = rand(0,3);
    $first = $role[$num1];
    $second = $role[$num2];
    echo $first,$second;
    ?>
```

Comment: i want to try this , but Dont Panic have an easier way .

Comment: sometimes its nice to get an idea of how something works on a lower level in case you want to modify it later but his is the easiest and most concise no doubt